# How to Change name of the NetConnectionProfile Using Set-NetConnectionProfile in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0, powershell-ise

I Tried Using  How to Change name of the NetConnectionProfile Using Set-NetConnectionProfile

```
$Profile=Get-NetConnectionProfile -InterfaceIndex 35
$Profile.Name = "Network1"
```

The Error is

```
"Name" is a ReadOnly property.
 At line:1 char:1
+ $Profile.Name = "Network1"
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) []
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : ReadOnlyCIMProperty
```

How to Change the Read only Property of the name?? Help Me

Comment: Can you Explain me how?

Comment: You should avoid putting tags in the question title.

Answer (score 6):

You can do this via direct registry edition.

Under the key
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\NetworkList\Profiles

you can see network profiles key (by it's uuid), and can change apropriate network ProfileName value.

Comment: `Get-ChildItem -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\NetworkList\Profiles\"` ➜ `$UUID = "{01234ABC-...}"` ➜ `$VALUE = "Network1"` ➜ `(Get-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\NetworkList\Profiles\$UUID").ProfileName` ➜ `Set-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\NetworkList\Profiles\$UUID" -Name ProfileName -Value $VALUE`

Answer (score 1):

The Name property is read-only, as you are reading these names.

```
$Profile=Get-NetConnectionProfile -InterfaceIndex 35
```

You are trying to Get a particular profile index name. Then declaring it as "Network1"

Learn About Using PowerShell Value Binding by Property Name

http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2013/03/25/learn-about-using-powershell-value-binding-by-property-name.aspx

Understanding and Using PowerShell Profiles

http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2013/01/04/understanding-and-using-powershell-profiles.aspx

Answer (score 1):

@Yvette is right. I don't think you can change this property. This property is from and decided by system.

If it is a domain network profile, it will be your domain name, eg. example.com and domain name is decided by domain controller.

If it is a WiFi network profile, it will be the SSID name of WiFi equipment and SSID is decided by your WiFi equipment.

Answer (score 1):

This attribute could be manually changed using secpol. So, I don't think this couldn't be changed. I only have to know HOW. :-)